# want to show data in new page or something like this where my table disappair

Tags: reactjs

hi i have a table with data i want when i clicked on any row its shows it id name and date of birth in blank page or any where ,,where my table disappair..here is code of my table

```
 <table className='content'>
      <tbody>

      <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Birth</th>
      {
        this.state.data.map(item=>{
          return (
            <tr onClick={this.handleclick}>
              <td >{item.id}</td>
              <td >{item.name}</td>
              <td >{item.dateofBirth}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })
      }
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

and here i want to write onclick method

```
handleclick(event,id,name,dateofBirth)
{
event.preventDefault();
console.log('click fun 
 active',this.state.data.id,this.state.name,this.state.dateofBirth);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing anything into your handleClick method, apart from `event`, which it's passed automatically.  If you want to pass all the other variables in, then you need to wrap the call in a closure function, like so:

```
 <table className='content'>
      <tbody>

      <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Birth</th>
      {
        this.state.data.map(item=>{
          return (
            <tr onClick={e => this.handleclick(e, item.id, item.name, item.dateofBirth)}
             key={item.id}>
              <td >{item.id}</td>
              <td >{item.name}</td>
              <td >{item.dateofBirth}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })
      }
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

You should also add a `key` to your tr.